# Are any large enterprises using Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm interested as sometimes I get friends who are developers telling me about their Ruby deployments, and most of them are in large enterprises which are using Java mainly, but have some small projects in Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the [success stories](http://success.heroku.com/) page on heroku.com.

Comment: Only one, bestbuy, but thanks for the link anyway. Know of any financial companies??

Comment: @Zubair: Financial companies tend to be a little picky about where they put their data (i.e. not out on the internet).

Answer (score 3):

Since you are not asking a very specific question, I also want to point out that your friends could deploy their Rails stuff to JBoss with [Torquebox](http://torquebox.org/).

Comment: It's for deploying on your own infrastructure. As I said, your question wasn't overly specific and you mentioned your friends work in large enterprises with existing Java infrastructure, so I figured they could also be interested Torquebox.